# Identifying the infinitive

Tags: infinitives

I was doing an exercise and I had to find the infinitive and also its type.

> ***And fools who came to scoff remained to pray.***

I think here there are 2 infinitives **to scoff** and **to pray**.
 But the answer is only ***to scoff***.

Comment: You are right. There are two infinitival clauses.

Comment: Yes, there are two: "scoff" and "pray".

Comment: I recognized this quote from a song, but it's actually from the poem 
["The Deserted Village" by Oliver Goldsmith.](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/44292/the-deserted-village)

Answer (score 1):

Heres a Reference to infinitives: https://literarydevices.net/infinitive/

As stated, its a pure **Verb** in its natural form that is always placed before the root verb "**to**". It can also be used as an **Adjective, Adverb or Noun**. You said the answer  is only **to scoff**. If that is the case, and your "question" is multiple choice, like a test, then that is the answer, and they simply haven't included it, if its not, then that is a mistake on the person who made the question.